# Find Radius of convergence of the given power series

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

> Find the radius of convergence of the power series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n+1}{n!} z^{n^3}$.

Let, $\displaystyle a_n=\frac{n+1}{n!} z^{n^3}$.

Then, $\displaystyle \left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=\frac{n+2}{(n+1)^2}|z|^{3n(n+1)+1}\longrightarrow 0$ for all $z\in \Bbb C$. So radius of convergence is $\infty$. Is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Cauchy-Hadamard,  I get $r=\dfrac 1{\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n^3]{\dfrac{n+1}{n!}}}=1$.

I think your answer above diverges when $\vert z\vert\gt1$.

Comment: When $|z|>1$ then my limit becomes $0.\infty=0$ in $\Bbb C_{\infty}$.

Comment: How your limit becomes $1$? I'm not getting. Can you please give some detail?

Comment: It took awhile, and i used an online calculator.

Comment: Exponentials grow faster than polynomials.   That's why I think your ratio test gives $\infty$.

Answer (score 3):

Your limit with the ratio test, tends to $0$ only if $|z|\le 1$. Indeed, if $|z|>1$, any polynomial $p(n)$ is $o\bigl(|z|^n\bigr)$, and *a fortiori* is  $\:o\bigl(|z|^{3n(n+1)+1}\bigr)$.